# Startup.cs does not appear to be running in Azure Function V4 (neither is program.cs)

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function V4 app (net 6) that loads an appsettings.json file for use with IConfiguration. Here's the code:

[image]

This works fine in dev but when I deploy to Azure, startup.cs appears to be ignored entirely. I've confirmed this using remote debugging.

I've also seen that in AF v4 you're supposed to use Program.cs instead of Startup.cs - I've tried this but found the same behavior.

Is there something wrong with my deployment process? What am I missing?

EDIT. .csproj file as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="{path-to-project}.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Add `<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="Startup.cs">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
` this in .csproj and check once.

Answer (score 0):

The Isolated process hosting model uses program.cs while the in-process hosting model uses startup.cs

Be sure you have the below attribute decorating your startup class for in-process (with the correct namespace, of course)

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
```